# Shouldn't we increase the required reputation to answer a protected question?

Tags: discussion

I sometimes see the protected questions not well answered by 20 rep user. So I thought it may be better to increase required rep to answer protected question. By this, we can:

- increase the answers level
- decrease the number of answers posted for a question
- encourage OP users to earn rep for answering some questions