# Title of questions closed as duplicate long time ago does not say "duplicate" in the app

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

Normally, the app will show "[duplicate]" in the title of questions closed as duplicate. However, turns out it only applies to questions closed aftera major change in the system that occured couple of years ago, as can be clearly seen in this screenshot:

> [image]

They are both closed as duplicate, [the first](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250825/shouldnt-we-increase-the-required-reputation-to-answer-a-protected-question) closed four hours ago while [the second](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7503/code-after-bullet-list-isnt-rendered-correctly) closed over five years ago.

Can this please be fixed?

Comment: Whoopsie I forgot it's for iOS app and I added a screenshot. @Mat

Comment: nice catch! It should show "duplicate", probably borked because it was closed long time ago, before the close system went through a major change.

Comment: I took the liberty to overwrite this as bug report and clarify, hope it's OK. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard sure! Thank you :)

Comment: Why are people voting to close?

Comment: Three were cast before the edits that clarified it's about the iOS app, one is "bandwagon effect" since it appeared in the close queue and someone didn't pay attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.4.3.1.

The app was using `[duplicate]` iff the closed reason was `duplicate`.  That question was closed as `exact duplicate`.